# Issue while installing wiki js

Tags: javascript, wiki.js

I have been trying to install Wiki js with Apache 2

while executing command:

```
curl -sSo- https://wiki.js.org/install.sh | bash
```

got this error:

```
bash: line 1: Redirecting: command not found
```

How to avoid this and execute the command?

Answer (score 0):

`curl https://wiki.js.org/install.sh` returns a [`301`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) status code with the `location` header set to `https://js.wiki/install.sh` and a response of `'Redirecting to https://js.wiki/install.sh'` which is piped to bash causing the error.

```
$ curl -I https://wiki.js.org/install.sh
HTTP/2 301 
cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-length: 42
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 05 Apr 2021 06:09:59 GMT
age: 102
server: Netlify
location: https://js.wiki/install.sh
x-nf-request-id: 73d12771-c0d3-4850-ace1-6abe963652e2-7616135
```

You can instruct `curl` to follow redirects using the `-L` flag.

```sh
curl -sL https://wiki.js.org/install.sh | bash
```

Or you could fetch the script from https://js.wiki/install.sh and pipe it to `bash`.

```sh
curl -s https://js.wiki/install.sh | bash
```